# Update prototype variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I'm working on a project where i need to return a framecount from a playing video via the method `video.prototype.getCurrentFrame()`. my script works pretty much fine exept that the number that is returned by this method is 'undefined'. I know that my problem has to do something with the scope of my variables but I'm new in javascript and I can't seem to make it work on my own ...

In my method `video.prototype.setUpPlayer` I have a function that allows me counting the framcount `'timeListener'` where I update a variable called frame; 
If I try to access this frame variable throught `video.prototype.getCurrentFrame()` it doesnt reach the updated value.

here is my code so far :

```
var Video = function(aVideoId){
this.videoId = aVideoId;
this.frame;
this.videoContainer; 
this.myPlayer;
this.timeListener;
this.progressListener;
};

Video.prototype.getCurrentFrame = function(){
    return this.frame;
}

Video.prototype.setVideoContainer = function(){
        videoContainer = $('<div>', {
        id: this.videoId,
        class: 'projekktor',
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
    });
    $('#innerContainer').html(videoContainer);
}

Video.prototype.setUpPlayer = function(){
    videoId = this.videoId;


    myPlayer = projekktor('#' + videoId, {
        controls: "true",
        volume: 0.5,
        preload: false,
        autoplay: true,
        playlist: [{
            0: {
                src: '/' + videoId + '.mp4',
                type: 'video/mp4'
            },
            1: {
                src: '/' + videoId + '.mov',
                type: 'video/mov'
            },
            2: {
                src: '/' + videoId + '.ogv',
                type: 'video/ogv'
            }
        }]
    }, function() { // call back
        myPlayer.addListener('time', timeListener);
        myPlayer.addListener('progress', progressListener);
    });

    timeListener = function(duration) {
            $('#currentTime').html(duration);
            frame = Math.round(duration * 25);
            $('#currentFrame').html(frame); 
                            return this.frame = frame;


        }

    progressListener = function(value) {
            $('#progress').html(Math.round(value))
            $('#progress2').html(myPlayer.getLoadProgress());
        }   
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: How are you calling the function `.getCurrentFrame()` You do not show any instances of `Video` in your code

Comment: One comment on your code: I would recommend you specfied the scopes of the variables your used in the functions. It is either private (by adding `var`, or adding `this` to make it accessible within the prototype). Otherwise you would create a lot of "garbage" in the global scope. This comment is unrelated to your question, though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `getCurrentFrame` from an instance of `Video`, not the prototype itself:

```
var video = new Video;
alert(video.getCurrentFrame());
```

The only way you could retrieve the current frame using the prototype would be to use `apply()` (which also requires an instance):

```
var video = new Video;
alert(Video.prototype.getCurrentFrame.apply(video));
```

---

**EDIT:** It appears that the `timeListener` callback is not executed in the context of the video's instance. You might have to explicitly *bind* the callback to the correct scope:

```
timeListener = function() 
    {
    //  ...
        this.frame = frame;
    //  ...
    }

var video = new Video;

// binding the correct context
myPlayer.addListener('time', timeListener.bind(video));
```

`this` in the `timeListener` closure is now `video`.

Comment: thanks, I already use an instance to use the function getCurrentFrame(). perhaps i should have been more precise about this. but my issue is that the this.frame does not change outside of the method setUpPlayer. so when I instanciate my video object and call it getCurrentFrame. the method return the value that has been put in the constructor in the first place (in my case nothing). When i want it to return the value updated